# How to get an input to call KO bound function on change?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have an `input` element that I'd like to call my function `searchQueryChanged` whenever `searchQuery` changes:

```
<input placeholder="Search…" type="text" name="q" data-bind="value: searchQuery, event: {change:searchQueryChanged}" autocomplete="off" />
```

In my view model, here's `searchQuery` and `searchQueryChanged`:

```
searchQuery = ko.observable('');

searchQueryChanged = function() {
    ....do some stuff....
},
```

However, when I type into the `input`, my function is not called. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say nothing gets called when you type into the textbox. I believe that with the change event, you have to move focus off of the textbox for the change to fire and your function to get called. If it was your intention to have the searchQueryChanged function called as you are typing in that textbox, you can try this, which will call searchQueryChanged after every keypress---

```
<input placeholder="Search…" type="text" name="q" data-bind="value: searchQuery, valueUpdate: 'keyup', event: { keyup: searchQueryChanged}" autocomplete="off" />
```

Comment: Tried this, still doesn't get called.

Comment: This may be overly obvious, but is that viewmodel being bound successfully, are they other knockout elements on the page that are behaving as expected? No other JS errors that may be causing this to break down?

Comment: @tnw It is should working good. Fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/X5eys/. Also you could use `keypress` instead of `keyup`.

Comment: @Gadget27 There are... not sure what's going on here.

Comment: Arg, after agonizing over this for days I found that it was not being properly bound after all. Since this was one of your comments, I'll accept this answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to register your own subscriptions to be notified of changes to observables, you can call their subscribe function. For example,

```
searchQuery.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    alert("The search query is " + newValue);
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/W3kD6/)** with working example added

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though you want the function to fire as soon as you type something. If that is the case then you're missing the following property:

valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'

as documented here: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html

Example:
HTML

```
<input placeholder="Search…" type="text" name="q" data-bind="value: searchQuery, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" autocomplete="off" />
```

JS
One way to subscribe to changes is simply to subscribe to the observable:

```
searchQuery.subscribe(searchQueryChanged);

function searchQueryChanged(value) {
    //value is the latest value that triggered the change
    ....do some stuff....
}
```

This should trigger a change event every time the user presses a key.

This is the way you should do it Knockout as oppose to relying on the change event.